# Next.js imports from root directory: is it valid to start an import with a slash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

This import works, but I can't find any documentation saying that it's valid:

```
// rather than do a crazy nested import like this
import { myUtil } from '../../../../../lib/utils'

// this appears to work just fine
import { myUtil } from '/lib/utils'
```

I see where the [official answer](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) is to set up a config file with a `@` alias, so I suppose I will just do that to be compliant. Just thought it was curious that this import worked just fine. I am using the default configuration for a Next.js project set up with `create-next-app`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your case, but if the top folder is in the root directory, you can use this

```
import { myUtil } from './lib/utils'
```

I'm guessing that's what's happening, even though you don't have the period in yours.